# Are there any open-source trading bots out there?

Tags: exchanges, trading, open-source, bots, arbitrage

Has anyone published an open-source trading bot that runs on a Bitcoin exchange?

Comment: Google results contain several such bots.

Comment: Instead of commenting each answer I'll write it here. All answers on this page can be improved by adding a little bit of explanation about the software that you're linking to. Answers with just links are not very good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a simple market maker bot in Python: https://github.com/chrisacheson/liquidbot

This software allows you to place orders on MtGox market.

> Liquidbot uses ezl's wrapper code to interface with MtGox: https://github.com/ezl/mtgox

Aricie runs a hosted market maker bot platform: https://dnnbitcoin.aricie.com/default.aspx

Answer (score 5):

- ## [ga bitbot](http://code.google.com/p/ga-bitbot/source/browse)

  from the project page:

  > ga-bitbot is a distributed genetic algorithm tuned automated mtgox trading system for Bitcoin which includes market data collection, gene client/server, reporting tools, and automated trading.
  >
  > The intention of this project is to create a high frequency capable trade platform for the bitcoin p2p currency.
- ## [bitcoin arbitrage](https://github.com/maxme/bitcoin-arbitrage)

  From the project page:

  > bitcoin-arbitrage - opportunity detector and automated trading
  >   It gets order books from supported exchanges and calculate arbitrage opportunities between each markets. It takes market depth into account.
  >
  > Currently supported exchanges to get data:
  >
  > MtGox (USD, EUR)
  >   Bitstamp (USD, ~EUR)
  >   Bitcoin24 (EUR)
  >   Bitfloor (USD)
  >   Bitcoin-Central (EUR)
  >   BTC-e (USD, EUR)
  >   Intersango (EUR)
  >   Bitfinex (USD)
  >
  > Currently supported exchanges to automate trade:
  >
  > MtGox (EUR, USD)
  >   Bitstamp (USD)
  >   Bitcoin-Central (EUR) - closed
  >
  > (under MIT licence)
  >
  > *TODO:
  >
  > Tests
  >   Write documentation
  >   Add other exchanges:
  >   icbit
  >   BitFinex
  >   Update order books with a WebSocket client for supported exchanges (MtGox, Bitcoin-Central)
  >   Better history handling for observer "HistoryDumper" (Redis ?)
  >   Move EUR / USD from a market to an other:
  >   Coupons
  >   Ripple ?
  >   Negative Operations
  >   use Litecoin or other cryptocurrencies trades

Comment: Please add a description, do not post just an URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one also https://github.com/rokj/bitcoin_dealer.

From the README file on the repo:

*Bitcoin dealer is simple Django program (trading bot) for trading bitcoins currently only on MtGox exchange.*

*Bitcoin dealer supports MtGox API version 1 with following currencies: USD, EUR, GBP, PLN, CAD, AUD, CHF, CNY, NZD, RUB, DKK, HKD, SGD, THB, JPY and SEK.*

*Although program is really simple, it supports stop orders and maybe something more, but I am not really familiar with trading techniques and jargon.*

*Program is most useful for those who do not have time to watch price of bitcoin all the time, have a PC running all the time and know how to write few "Hello worlds" with two if cases.*

Also, the link is not dead at time of editing (21/07/2013).

Comment: Welcome here. Please add a description of the software, do not post just an URL.

Comment: Link is currently dead, so unless edited this answer is worthless now.

Comment: Link is now live again.

Answer (score 0):

When considering a bitcoin trading bot, you must decide where you will trade, generally which exchange you'd like to trade at, such as Binance or Poloniex. From there, you can either use a 'pre-packaged' strategy for buying and selling or developing your own based on various indicators.

I have developed a [youtube course where I describe the open source development of a crypto trading bot in python](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVTnyT4fUxYkvawbggo8-AQ), with [all crypto trading bot python code publicly available through github](http://www.github.com/Roibal). With this bot you can create and set your own strategies.

Other than my previous description, another well developed [crypto trading bot is 'Gekko'](https://gekko.wizb.it/), open source on NodeJS and can has great, easy functionality to create and [implement strategies with large community support](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAmuii96bcAhVL6YMKHTQVA4EQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgekkowarez.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw0O3m9z0sTrPAZhZNBOrDtv).