# Trading software

Tags: trading

I googled some time, but didn't find anything - is it possible to add btc market into software like meta trader? Or is there any (free) analysis software for that?

I just found info about some software (bitcointrader), which used to exist, but [that site](http://btc-trader.org/) is now an alias for another trading platform.

Comment: The same question was asked here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2472/516 with the one difference that they wanted it to be open source. For that reason, I won't vote to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=6019.0

Free analysis and charting software, registration required.

Comment: yeah, already using that!

Answer (score 2):

how about TradingView. it's web based charting tool and it's free (ex: look for the pair BITSTAMP:BTCUSD). also, it doesn't seem to be just limited to bitcoin.

https://www.tradingview.com/

https://www.tradingview.com/e/

Answer (score 0):

[Whaleclub](https://whaleclub.co) has a pretty stunning trading dashboard with alerts, news, and live technical analysis. It uses TradingView in the backend to pull some of that content as Daisy Jones mentioned.

If you're looking for more the data side of bitcoin exchanges, I'd use [Bitcoinity's data site](http://data.bitcoinity.org) which I think is the longest running and hence has the most historical data (volume, price, hashrate, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

There is almost no software for trading on several crypto exchanges.

I've found only that one - http://stocksharp.com/products/

TradingView as mentioned above unfortunately do not provide live trading capabilities.

Another projects like QTTrader are now dead.