# Windows trading software

Tags: trading

Is there any advanced trading software available for windows platform? I came across [goxtool](http://prof7bit.github.io/goxtool/), which is pretty much what I'd like to try, but runs only on linux.

I am looking for a client that offers more than just simple buy/sell orders - I don't mind if coding is involved (python, matlab, c++, whatever), I'd like to experiment with custom trading bots in small amounts of BTC.

Comment: Was answered on similar question here https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/67329/72071

Answer (score 1):

You could probably run goxtool in Python under Cygwin, since that would give you a terminal.  I'm not sure if that's the only Linux-specific thing it'd need, but it'd probably be a start.